# What is the use of throw() after a function declaration?

Tags: c++

Throw is defined as a `C++ expression` in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw. Syntactically, it is followed by an exception class name. For example:

```
int a = 1, b = 0; 
if (b==0){
    string m ="Divided by zero";
    throw MyException(m);       //MyException is a class that inherit std::exception class
}
```

However, I have seen other syntaxes with throw that I don't quite understand:

```
void MyFunction(int i) throw();     // how can we have an expression following a function definition?
```

or within a custom exception class, we also have:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
  MyException( const std::string m)
    : m_( m )
  {}

  virtual ~MyException() throw(){};               // what is throw() in this case? 
  const char* what() const throw() {                       // what are the parentheses called? 
      cout<<"MyException in ";
      return m_.c_str(); 
  }

private:
  std::string m_;
};
```

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is there a common syntax rule that allows an expression followed by a function definition?
2. Why do we have parenthesis following an expression throw? What are they called in C++?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec

Comment: "Throw is defined as a C++ expression" It is not. `throw` is a keyword with several uses.

Comment: Throw as an exception specification was removed in C++17. Starting from C++17 you can't even use that.

Comment: Well, I have to say that the _throw expression_ at the top of the [linked page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) could lead somebody thinkging that `throw` _is_ the expression. That title, instead, just means that you can write `throw some_expression` in the code in order to `throw` that `some_expression`.

Comment: There is another interesting valid syntax for try blocks: Function try with the keyword try outside the braces, it can even come before the member initialization list of constructors.

Comment: @Enlico that's the page for throw expressions, it is listing that one use. [Here's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/throw) the page for keyword `throw`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`throw()` is not a `throw` expression. It is a completely independent syntax construct that just happens to look the same (C++ likes to reuse keywords for multiple purposes instead of reserving more identifiers). The position where `throw()` is used in your examples is not a position where the grammar of the language expects an expression, therefore it can't be a `throw` expression. Additionally `()` is not a valid expression (as would be required after `throw` in a `throw` expression) either.

It is the syntax to declare a non-throwing [dynamic exception specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) for a function, meaning it declares that the function does not throw any exceptions.

The syntax has been deprecated since C++11 and has finally completely been removed from the language with C++20. Therefore it shouldn't be used anymore.

The exact mechanism of the dynamic exception specification has no replacement, but specifically the non-throwing declaration `throw()` has been superseded by the [`noexcept` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) (since C++11). So all uses of `throw()` on a function declaration in old code should be updated to `noexcept` instead.